# React js Failed to compile Errer

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I moved to windows 11 from Linux , so i imported all my code from Linux..to windows . So whenever i try to run a react project , I get a compile error stating :-

`

```
./src/Componets/shop/products.JSON
Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = __w...'
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

`

[image]

Comment: There something wrong in your products.json file in shop folder please share that file code as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.